# Depending on first drop list selection, second drop down list should contain related contents

Tags: java, struts2

Depending on first drop down list item selection, i want a second drop down list should contain related contents. How can i do this in java?
For instance,
Let say, first Drop down list contains a name of countries, and second drop down list contains the names of states. And if i select a particular country, say "India", name from a first drop down list then second list should show only related states of country i.e states of "India". 
And both lists are dynamic.

Comment: Are you talking about swing component or a HTML one?

Comment: There is `<s:doubleselect>` tag in Struts2.

Comment: @ Sudhanshu, i have to show that on JSP page.

Comment: @ Anand Shankar, how can i get that county values and state values from database in a java-script?

Answer (score 0):

This is more Javascript than Java and struts 2.

There are two options you can get a Map with the first drop down's values as key and the other dropdown's values related to that item.

Then when the first combobox's value is selected you can get the values form the javascript map and set it to the second dropdown.

Other option is to send an ajax request on the first dropdown's selection and pupulate the second dropdown from the results.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using javascript for this:

- either with ajax, by making a struts action that returns the options, and reload your `select` content, for example with jquery:

  `$("#stateSelect").load('http://host/myStateAction.do?country=' + country);`
- or loading the whole country/state mapping on page load, and update the second list with pure javascript with no server call. To do this you can for example store in each country `option` a `data-states` attributes, containing the corresponding states.

`<option value="code" data-states="state1,state2,state3">countryName</option>`

Otherwise if you want to avoid javascript, you can submit your form when a change event is fired, and on the server side (struts action) you fill the second list based on the value of the first, and redirect to the form page. `<select onchange="documents.forms['myForm'].submit()">`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JavaScript like below:
 This is better to handle rather than from java side:

Here is your sample HTML File:

```
<select id="country" name="country" aria-required="true" class="required">
    <option value="">Select Your Country</option>
    <option value="USA">India</option>
    <option value="CA">Pakisthan</option>
</select>
<p><label for="state">Select Your State<span title="required">*</span>
</label></p>
<select id="state" name="state" aria-required="true" class="required">
    <option value="" selected="">Select Your State</option>
    <optgroup label="India">
        <option value="WB">West Bengal</option>
        <option value="BH">Bihar</option>        
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Pakisthan">
        <option value="LH">Lahore</option>
        <option value="IB">Islamabad</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Here is your sample JavaScript:

```
var stateVar = $('#state option, #state optgroup');
stateVar.hide();
$('#country').change(function () {
    stateVar.hide();
    $("#state optgroup[label='" + $(this).find(':selected').html() + "']")
        .children()
        .andSelf()
        .show();
});
```

You can use AJAX as well and it might be a little complicated to you, so better to use simple JavaScript.
You can try this approach and let me know in case of any concern.