# how to update one value from drop down list based on calculation?

Tags: jquery, html

For example: I got dropdown list from  sum assured, and i would like to automatically calculate the Premium. For example if 30000 for sum assured is selected, then the premium 361.30 will be selected in the premium select list.

```
<select id="sumAssured"> 
<option value="10000">10000</option> 
<option value="20000">20000</option> 
<option selected="selected" value="30000">30000</option>  
<option value="50000">50000</option>
<option value="100000">100000</option> 
</select>
```

The premium 361.30 will be automatically calculated on the backend.

Suggested to use Jquery, thanks :)

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery change event.

```
<input type="text" id="tb" />

$("#sumAssured").change(function()
{ 
       var selectedvalue = $(this).val();
     // do your calculation
     $("#tb").val(selectedvalue);
});
```

working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XMQ3V/)

Answer (score 0):

You need not to use JQuery for this, JavaScript will do for you.
Use the script below:

```
var stateVar = $('#selected option, #selected optgroup');
    stateVar.hide();
    $('#sumAssured').change(function () {
        stateVar.hide();
        $("#selected optgroup[label='" + $(this).find(':selected').html() + "']")
            .children()
            .andSelf()
            .show();
  });
```

For more details with the HTML also you can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829948/depending-on-first-drop-list-selection-second-drop-down-list-should-contain-rel/15830286#15830286).
Please let me know in case of any concern.